# OTP Verification in flutter without Firebase

Tags: android, ios, flutter

After registering a new user with email and password using firebase flutter. Is there any way to verify his phone number without a firebase phone authentication so the same user will not be registered with email/password and phone number (I want to register him once using his email and password and verify his phone number)?

Answer (score 8):

**(Currently this package is outdated.It does not support Null Safety)**.
You can try flutter_otp package I think it's the best option,
visit [flutter_otp 0.3.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp) for more info.

Try the below example

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_otp/flutter_otp.dart';

    // Now instantiate FlutterOtp class in order to call sendOtp function
    FlutterOtp otp = FlutterOtp();
    class SendOtp extends StatelessWidget {
       String phoneNumber = "93XXXXXXXX"; //enter your 10 digit number
       int minNumber = 1000;
       int maxNumber = 6000;
       String countryCode ="+91"; // give your country code if not it will take +1 as default

  
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("send otp using flutter_otp ")),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
             child: Text("Send"),
             onPressed: () {
               // call sentOtp function and pass the parameters

            otp.sendOtp(phoneNumber, 'OTP is : pass the generated otp here ',
                minNumber, maxNumber, countryCode);
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/64712867/6997976

Answer (score 5):

I think you could try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp

and there are also a lot of websites that providers OTP SMS Services.

**Tip:** You can even use Firebase Auth since it also suits your case.

In firebase, you can just link (something like merge) the accounts that are created with Email and Phone using like this `emailUser.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(phoneUserCredential)`

 In this case, your app will consist of one user with that Email and Phone.

 Additional Benefit is that you don't want to store phone numbers in a separate database. 
After linking both the accounts, you can just simply use [`user.displayName`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#displayname) and [`user.phoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#phonenumber) to fetch your Email and Phone.

**Refer:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking